BeforeDelete when deleting multiple rows with a query
I have a [Before Delete] data macro that works when I delete one row manually.
When I try to delete rows with a query I get

Run-time error '2486'
You can't carry out this action at the present time.

If I click "End", I see

Unknown Access database engine error

Why would Access care whether the delete is occurring with a mouse-click or a query? I thought the point of these things was that they were agnostic of 'how', and would always record deletes regardless of context.
The macro is making use of a custom function that records some details about the deletion in an audit table (runs SQL).
It would seem being unable to delete rows via a query nullifies the use of delete-related data macro.

So, after continuing to chug away at this, and trying alternatives (like using the "Create Record" to log the changes) which did work...   On a whim I tried using "CurrentDb.Execute" rather than "DoCmd.RunSQL" to run the query that is inside the function - and voila! It worked!
Now - I still don't understand why it complained at all, but for me this is significant because I needed the function approach for the After Update data macro (i.e., using the SetLocalVar option to a value that uses my custom function), because otherwise it would likely have required too many entries to try to use Create Record for the After Update data macro (due to the often large numbers of fields and having to address EVERY field independently in order to trap which changed.)
I'm glad that there appears to be a way to call your own function that runs SQL - in conjunction with a data macro. Now I can have Adds, Edits, and Deletes all logged to an audit table, indicating key field and date/time that it occurred. Cool!

Be careful with CurrentDb.Execute as it will not show any message in case of an error. If you want to use it always use it like this: CurrentDb.Execute, dbFailOnErrors
Like this you will be notified in case of errors.

True.
I kind of forgot that.
